# Why rsync --sparse produce bigger qcow2 files than original qcow2 files

Tags: linux, image, rsync, sparse-matrix, proxmox

## Problem:

When i´am copying the whole disk with my virtual machines onto anemty disk with rsync --sparse the disk images (qcow2 files) on the new Disk are bigger then the original files.

*Old Disk:*
/dev/sda1 => /ssdstor

*New Disk:*
/dev/sdb1 => /new

### Details:

*Hardware:*
2x SSD Curcial M500 960GB Firmware MU5

*OS:* Proxmox 3.4

*Filesyste:* XFS

*Command:*

```
rsync -axHv --force --progress --stats --sparse /ssdstor/ /new/
```

*Rsync Version:*
*dpkg -L | grep rsync*

```
ii  rsync                                         993.1.1-1                     amd64        fast, versatile, remote (and local) file-copying tool
```

- file / disk comparison after first copy*
  ( to check everything was transfered correctly )

rsync -axHv --dry-run --force --progress --stats --sparse /ssdstor/ /new/

```
sending incremental file list

Number of files: 90,545 (reg: 70,269, dir: 9,395, link: 10,817, dev: 4, special: 60)
Number of created files: 0
Number of deleted files: 0
Number of regular files transferred: 0
Total file size: 634,456,255,674 bytes
Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 65,536
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 2,097,654
Total bytes received: 9,993

sent 2,097,654 bytes  received 9,993 bytes  1,405,098.00 bytes/sec
total size is 634,456,255,674  speedup is 301,025.86 (DRY RUN)
```

*mount | egrep '(sda|sdb)'*

```
/dev/sda1 on /ssdstor type xfs (rw,noatime,nodiratime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
/dev/sdb1 on /new type xfs (rw,noatime,nodiratime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
```

*df -h  | egrep '(sda|sdb)'*

```
/dev/sda1             894G    388G  506G   44% /ssdstor
/dev/sdb1             894G    430G  465G   49% /new
```

*ls -alshR /ssdstor | grep qcow2*

```
77G -rw-r--r--  1 root root 103G Jul 14 09:09 vm-100-disk-1.qcow2
6,2G -rw-r--r--  1 root root  14G Jul 14 09:07 vm-101-disk-1.qcow2
2,0G -rw-r--r--  1 root root 4,1G Jul 14 09:07 vm-101-disk-2.qcow2
17G -rw-r--r--  1 root root 61G Feb 18 09:10 vm-102-disk-1.qcow2
40G -rw-r--r--  1 root root 78G Jul 14 09:06 vm-103-disk-1.qcow2
40G -rw-r--r--  1 root root 41G Jul 14 09:05 vm-103-disk-2.qcow2
31G -rw-r--r--  1 root root 44G Jul 14 09:05 vm-104-disk-1.qcow2
5,2G -rw-r--r--  1 root root 41G Mai  1 01:00 vm-105-disk-2.qcow2
63G -rw-r--r--  1 root root 65G Jul 14 10:04 vm-106-disk-1.qcow2
26G -rw-r--r--  1 root root 65G Jul 14 09:14 vm-107-disk-2.qcow2
51G -rw-r--r--  1 root root 51G Mai 19 21:21 vm-108-disk-1.qcow2
```

*ls -alshR /new | grep qcow2*

```
79G -rw-r--r--  1 root root 103G Jul 14 09:09 vm-100-disk-1.qcow2
6,2G -rw-r--r--  1 root root  14G Jul 14 09:07 vm-101-disk-1.qcow2
2,0G -rw-r--r--  1 root root 4,1G Jul 14 09:07 vm-101-disk-2.qcow2
17G -rw-r--r--  1 root root 61G Feb 18 09:10 vm-102-disk-1.qcow2
40G -rw-r--r--  1 root root 78G Jul 14 09:06 vm-103-disk-1.qcow2
41G -rw-r--r--  1 root root 41G Jul 14 09:05 vm-103-disk-2.qcow2
37G -rw-r--r--  1 root root 44G Jul 14 09:05 vm-104-disk-1.qcow2
34G -rw-r--r--  1 root root 41G Mai  1 01:00 vm-105-disk-2.qcow2
63G -rw-r--r--  1 root root 65G Jul 14 10:04 vm-106-disk-1.qcow2
33G -rw-r--r--  1 root root 65G Jul 14 09:14 vm-107-disk-2.qcow2
51G -rw-r--r--  1 root root 51G Mai 19 21:21 vm-108-disk-1.qcow2
```

Has anyone an idea?

More Tests:

cp --sparse=always vm-105-disk-2.qcow2 vm-105-disk-2.qcow2.new

```
5,2G -rw-r--r--  1 root root 41G Jul 16 08:07 vm-105-disk-2.qcow2
 34G -rw-r--r--  1 root root 41G Jul 16 11:51 vm-105-disk-2.qcow2.new
```

Comment: Looking at the output of `ls`, they seem to be the same size, despite the `df` output.  How do things compare if you *don't* use `--sparse`?

Comment: They have the same "non sparse" size, correct. Good question, i tested it with "vm-105-disk-2.qcow2" now and the result is, i get the same size like the "non sparse size" 41G. That means --sparse work but not correctly?